# Run Github projects on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, github

I am not a Wordpress developer at all, but recently i have build a Wordpress website and now i want to run my Github projects in my Wordpress website.

Just think like this --

```
if there is a new repository in my Github account 
it should shows up in my wordpress account as well
means there will be a pipe line between my wordpress website and my github account
```

More specifically i would say ---

```
How to Run PHP projects in WordPress
```

So how can i implement it !!!

Should i use the Github api OR there are some other ways to solve this problem !

I have search a lot to solve this problem but somehow i did not get a single solution what i am looking for, Do anyone knows any solution of this problem !!!

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? I'm not sure what you asking. When you say "Github Projects", what are you thinking that is? The code page on GitHub? In theory you could use iframes to embed github into your blog, but it would look weird. You could also use the GitHub API and write a WordPress plugin to manage that, but that would be a fairly large project and not something you can easily answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JeremyHarris i have updated my question, can you kindly have a look ...

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/github-embed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the closest solution to what you are describing is to use a plugin such as [GitHub Embed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/github-embed/) by Lee Willis.

The project description says:

> Plugin that allows you to embed details from github just by pasting in the URL as you would any other embed source. Currently supports:
>
> - Repositories
> - User profiles
> - Project milestone summaries
> - Project contributors